# Getting ssl certificate from godaddy and domain name, after I upload to Heroku they tell me to pay 7$they need me to

Tags: ssl, heroku, web-hosting, cloudflare, godaddy-api

I bought domain name from GoDaddy, after that I try to get ssl certificate, so I bought from GoDaddy also, after I upload to heruko manually with crt and key, they tell me to get pay another 7$, for sorry I don't have a cpanel on my godaddy and I can't pay webhosting is there are another way to setup this ssl cert, I use cloudflare but They need also cpanel is there are any free way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You get it wrong folk. From the Heroku you can get the ssl privilege only on Hobby dyno.
If you don't want to pay them and also want `https` on your website then it's possible with the help of Cloudflare.

In Heroku and Cloudflare there is no role of cpanel.

Check here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS